# Saving IOS dictionary with arrays as keys

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am working with Tapku's Calendar, and i want to save some values that will be user inputed.

But i am kind of stumbled on how i would achive this, here is the layout:

```
// allocate the arrays and dictionary
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *dateValueArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// set array values
[dateValueArray addObject:@"first string"];
[dateValueArray addObject:@"Second string"];

// set dictionary with date as key, and array as value
[dict setObject:dateValueArray forKey:testdate];
```

The dictionary dict, will be the only Dictionary, but since that dictionary uses arrays for objects, i would have multiple arrays.

So, lets say there are multiple dates registerd in "dict", different keys would have to use different arrays? Sorry i am abit confused my self here.

Is there any way i can use 1 array to store all the strings associated with different dictionary keys ?

**EDIT 1**

Elaboration:

The whole idea is that the user can input text that are associated with dates.

I will need to store these values and i will need to store which date they are associated to.

So i have multiple values in an array, associated with 1 date in a dictionary.

And keeping in mind that i will have to store this, i would like to know how i should assign the values to the dates.

**EDIT 2:**

Basically what i need for the Array is something like AddObject ForKey

Edit 3

More elaboration::

Basically i want to access the values in this manner:

```
[date1][note1] 
[date1][note2] 
[date2][note1] 
[date2][note2]
```

And the amount of values in both date and note are variable.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you really want? The question itself become a little bit confusing. Do you want one array to store all the strings that are inside the arrays, which are in your dict?

Comment: You could, I guess. But in that case each key would need to be associated to an index into the array from which the objects related to that key are. That seems to become much more complex to build and maintain.

Comment: It seems a little weird to me that you would be looking up the dates by the arrays.

Comment: Why don't you create an array of dictionaries, the dictionary with keys date and notes. Notes will be an array of notes made on a particular day. Don't create a new dictionary if there is already a dictionary for same date. Is that how you want it?

Comment: I edited my answer after seeing your edit. Please tell me if thats what you were looking for.

Comment: Let me see if I understand what you are asking: After having added an array to you dictionary, you want to add another item to the array stored in the dictionary for a given key?

Comment: Yes! partially, but i only want 1 array and 1 dictionary, i do not want 10 arrays holding different strings associated with different keys in the dictionary.

basically i want to access the values in this manner:

[date1][note1]
[date1][note2]
[date2][note1]
[date2][note2]

And the amount of values in both date and note are variable

Comment: I am confused as to what you are trying to do then.  Do you want a separate list of notes for each date, or do you want a list of dates and a list of notes?  If you want a list of notes for each date, what you want is basically what you have, a dictionary with several arrays stored in it.  If you want a common list of both dates and notes, then why not just have two arrays?

Comment: i want a list of notes for each date, but i only want to use 1 array if that is somehow possible

Comment: Why do you want only 1 array?  One array for each date sounds like exactly what you want.

Comment: Edited my answer again. I insist, you should use a dict of arrays, there's absolutely no reason to use just one array. There's nothing you can do if one array that you can't do with multiples

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking about, what you want is the property of NSDictionary `allKeys` which is an array of all the keys in that dictionary.

Comment: I think i explained it incorectly, i am sorry.

I need the Array to be able to hold multiple values that are associated with a single date, but there will be multiple dates. So i would need each date to target its own segment of the array with some identifier, i am a little new to IOS programming, this was much simpler in PHP: $array[date][0][value] $array[date][1][value] etc

Answer (score 0):

Now I see your edit. You are in the right way. To perform what you are looking for, do something like this:

First, allocate your dict somewhre:

```
// allocate the arrays and dictionary
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
```

Now, everytime you get a new date with a new string, first check if there's the first string for that date. If yes, create a new array. If not, add your string inside the previously array.

```
NSMutableArray *valuesForDate = dict[givenDate];

if (!valuesForDate)
{
    valuesForDate [NSMutableArray new];
    dict[givenDate] = valuesForDate
}

[valuesForDate addObject:@"first string for dateGiven"];
[valuesForDate addObject:@"Second string for dateGiven"];
```

Now you can retrieve the values with something like you wanted:

```
NSString *test = dict[date1][0]; //first string associated for date1
NArray *allStringsForDate2 = dict[date2]; //array with all the strings for date2
```

Comment: THe issue is i would need to save the array and the dictionary, and then there should only be 1 array and not 2 arrays, valuesForDate1 and valuesForDate2 should be 1 array, that could be accessed in the different ways

Comment: Why exactly do you need them to be inside just in one array? Once the strings are associated with dates, it would be better and easier to keep them in different arrays. You can save/persist this structure like there were just one dict/array

Comment: Becouse they are variable on user input, i would have to create arrays on the fly

Comment: Edited my answer again. I insist, you should use a dict of arrays, there's no good and elegant way to accomplish this just with one array

Answer (score 0):

You can try using NSMapTable instead of NSDictionary, which is much more flexible but also much harder to use. You'll also find it hard to find anyone knowing the answers if you have questions about NSMapTable. But you can definitely create an NSMapTable which will use pointers of objects as keys, instead of the values.